# Nonharmonic solutions of Laplace's equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $f \colon U \to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function, where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here twice differentiable means that all the second partial derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} (\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} f)$ exist (however they are not necessarily continuous). Suppose $\Delta f = 0$, i.e. $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2} f = 0$. Does this imply that $f$ is harmonic, i.e. that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable? (For $n = 1$ it does, so let's assume that $n \ge 2$.)

Remark: I have read somewhere that if $f$ is weakly harmonic, then it is harmonic. However I think the second derivatives of $f$ here are not necessarily the same as the weak second derivatives. So my guess is that there is a counterexample, but I was not able to find one. Such a counterexample would be an obstruction to the extension of the Lebesgue integral to more general functions, such that the Fubini theorem and the Newton-Leibniz theorem both remain true.

Comment: This isn't really a satisfying answer, so i've made it a comment, but the Laplacian is an elliptic operator, so if $\Delta f\in C^\infty$ then so is $f$, at least for square integrable $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a counterexample in $n\ge3$ dimensions. With $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ denoting the Euclidean norm, set
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x_1x_2x_3\lVert x\rVert^{-n-4},&{\rm if\ }x\not=0,\cr
0,&{\rm if\ }x=0.
\end{cases}
$$
This is harmonic on $x\not=0$, has first and second order derivatives at the origin, but $f$ along with all its derivatives are discontinuous at the origin.

Note that, $f=c\frac{\partial^3(\lVert x\rVert^{-n+2})}{\partial x_1\partial x_2\partial x_3}$ is a third order derivative of a harmonic function, so is harmonic (away from the origin). As $f$ vanishes whenever all but two coordinates are zero, it along with its first order derivatives all vanish on the coordinate axes. So, $f$ along with all its first and second order derivatives vanish at the origin.

Next, here's a counterexample in $n=2$ dimensions. Using $i=\sqrt{-1}$, define $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ by,
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\Re\left[\exp\left(-(x+iy)^{-4}\right)\right],&{\rm if\ }(x,y)\not=0,\cr
0,&{\rm if\ }x=y=0.
\end{cases}
$$
As the real part of an analytic function, $f$ is harmonic away from the origin. Also, $f$ along with its derivatives to any order are bounded by a multiple of a power of $\lVert x\rVert$ mutiplied by $\exp(-\lVert x\rVert^{-4})$ on any bounded subset of the coordinate axes (outside of the origin). So, $f$ together with all partial derivatives to all orders exist and are zero at the origin. On the other hand, $f$ is not continuous at the origin.
Note, this also gives an alternative counterexample to the first one above in $n\ge3$ dimensions by making $f$ independent of $x_3,\ldots,x_n$.

Comment: But is this a counterexample to what was asked?

Comment: @Deane: Yes, I think so. It satisfies all of the properties asked for in the question but is not even continuous (so not harmonic). What do you think is missing?

Comment: It is not a solution at the origin. 

Comment: It is. As $f$ vanishes on the coordinate axes we have $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i^2}=0$ at the origin, so $\Delta f=0$ there.

Comment: These are nice counterexamples. I just realized I made a mistake in the question. By twice differentiable I really meant twice totally differentiable, which is stronger than just the existence of the partial derivatives. (In particular, the function should be continuous, even $\mathcal{C}^1$.)

Comment: @eb80: That changes thing then. If $f$ is continuous (locally integrable is probably enough) and the partial derivatives exist with $\Delta f=0$ then $f$ is smooth.

Comment: @George: Why? Do you have a reference for that? If $f$ is locally integrable, then you can ask whether $f$ is a solution of the weak Laplace equation, i.e. $\int f \, \Delta g = 0$ for every smooth $g$ with compact support. However I think this is not the same as the Laplace equation here, because the second derivatives of $f$ might be non-integrable. More precisely:
\[
\int f \Delta g = \int(\Delta f)g-\int\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f\right)g\right).
\]
Is the last term zero? If we can change the order of $\int$ and $\sum$, then yes.

Comment: The  general result, as I mentioned in my answer is the following: if $f$ is a *distribution* satisfying  $\Delta f=0$ in the sense of  distributions, then $f$ is smooth. A priori you don't even need to know that $f$ is locally integrable. Also, the first of the above counterexample is wrong for a simple reason:  the function $f$ is not differentiable  at $0$. Try defining the directional derivative $\lim_{t\to 0} (f(th)-f(0))t^{-1}$,  when $n=3$ and $h=(1,1,1)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ you will see why.

Comment: @Liviu: In my answer, $f$ has all first and second order *partial* derivatives. I took this as what the question was asking for, because of the sentence "Here twice differentiable means that all the second partial derivatives exist". In that sense, it is a counterexample to the question. If the derivative of $f$ is required to exist, not just partial derivatives, then that changes things and there are no counterexamples.

Comment: The partial  derivatives at $0$ do not exist. The function is not even continuous at $0$ because it is not bounded in a  neighborhood of $0$.  Moreover your function is not even harmonic because it satisfies the equation $\Delta f= const. \partial^3_{x_1,x_2,x_3}\delta_0$. The distribution $\partial^3_{x_1,x_2,x_3}\delta_0$ is not trivial.

Comment: You produced a function which is harmonic in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus 0$ hence is smooth there. Your function is homogeneous of  degree$2-n$ and its $k$-th order derivatives are homogeneous of degree $2-n-k$.   A nonzero function on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus 0$ which is homogeneous of degree $\alpha$  extends to a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if $\alpha\geq 0$.

Comment: My (Bazin's) answer and Liviu Nicolaescu's answer are correct and contradict George Lowther's answer. The point is to decide what means $\Delta u=0$. In the sense of distributions, it is clear and both answers mentioned above give a clearcut result. Now if you accept the "counterexample" above which is missing a point, the Laplace equation is not satisfied in the distribution sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general result.  If $f$ is a distribution on $U$ and $\Delta f\in C^\infty(U)$, then $u\in C^\infty(U)$.  More generally, you can replace $\Delta$ with any properly supported elliptic pseudodifferential operator on $U$.  In particular, any  elliptic operator with smooth coefficients is a properly supported  elliptic pseudodifferential operator.

Answer (score 2):

If $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$, $f$ is a distribution on $U$ such that $\Delta f$ is analytic on $U$, then $f$ is analytic on $U$. This hypoellipticity result is true for any elliptic differential operator with analytic coefficients.